# win10 + python3 управление exe приложеним

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

необходимо запустить exe приложение на win10, затем после некоторых манипуляций перезагрузить это приложение
запускаю приложение с помощью:

```
def start_app():
    os.chdir(cfg.app_path) 
    subprocess.Popen("app.exe")
```

Вопрос:

1. как закрыть это приложение?
2. После запуска app.exe, при повторном вызове
   функции start_app приложение "разворачивается" на передний план. Правильный ли такой метод, или для этого есть иной способ?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, начнем с того, что когда вы запускаете какое-либо приложение c GUI через `subprocess.Popen()`, то это, то же самое, что и запуск через `cmd` (либо руками).

Соответственно, если вы его руками открываете и оно у вас встает на передний план, то так будет и при запуске через скрипт.

Что касается закрытия, то самым простым вариантом будет:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /IM app.exe /F")
```